# port 25 smtp port connection refused

Tags: 12.04, postfix, smtp, dovecot

I just settup my postfix on my VPS with the help of this guide: https://www.exratione.com/2012/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1204-postfix-dovecot-mysql/

Everything works, can send mails, recive it, etc etc....on localhost.
when i try to acces  it from my own computer, nothing happens, and when i try `telnet mail.example.com smtp` it says connection refused.

every config is just like in that guide.

Comment: Looks like some of your mail server ports are blocked. Check the firewall settings.

Comment: i turned off the firewall and the problem still exists

Comment: I recommend you try setting up the smtp server once again - follow the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/email-services.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is common for isp's to block port 25 or intercept all traffic on it to prevent spam.

In your case does it look like your isp is blocking the port on your local connection. Your remote server is working cause your VPS provider is not blocking the port.